# menu goes up when click on it (in mobile view)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

i'm using [sticky.js](http://stickyjs.com/) and it's works well but when i resize browser like mobile view and click it main menu button goes up and i can't close it , i have to up to see it
what should i do that it stick to top then show subsets ?

[live demo](http://bloodmyst.com/)

i use this jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#header").sticky({
        className : 'sticky-header'
    });
});
```

if you need more detail please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `.sticky-header ul.slimmenu`, change the styles to:

```
font-size:32px;
position:fixed;
top:50px;
box-shadow:none;
```

You want it to be `50px` from top (so it doesn't overlap the menu bar) and `fixed` so it always stays there.

However, this should be put in a media query so it only applies to the mobile version. It will break the desktop version.